# How to remove the history of roscd?

Tags: ros, roscd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to download echo_openni package on my ROS repository, and I rosmake it successfully.

But after I rm -r that package, I use roscd echo_openni it shows that package couldn't find.

But that package is really on the /opt...

How to clean the history of roscd?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44789/how-to-remove-the-history-of-roscd?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-09-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

.ros contains a rospack_cache. That might be it.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-09-29**:
I found that when I remove ~/.ros/rosstack_cache solve this problem~Thank you~

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-30**:
Instead of deleting the cache, just do a `rospack profile` to rebuild it.